# How to subscribe to DB changes with Floor in Flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, floor, bloc

I'm trying to use an ability of [Floor package](https://pub.dev/packages/floor) to subscribe to db changes getting a stream like that:

```
  @Query(
      'SELECT * from word INNER JOIN word_category_join ON word.id=word_category_join.word_id '
      'WHERE word_category_join.category_id=:categoryId')
  Stream<List<Word>> getWordsForCategoryAsStream(int categoryId);
```

And using it in a StreamBuilder in my views.

And according to the documentation, my stream should return a new snapshot every time the Word table changed, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you update the database? are you using floor package itself to update the db?

Comment: @Sahandevs sure, using @insert/@update annotations

Comment: Post more code, especially the UI part with your `StreamBuilder`. I just went through the process and it works. With more code, we could help.